# Cannot create a PARTITION BY DATE(timestamp)

Tags: google-bigquery

Hello I am using my personal GCP account to play around in Bigquery, and I am still within my free-tier range (a billing account is linked, but no fees incurred yet).

So I create a table to fetch baseball.games_wide table from bigquery-public-dataset. The following is my simple CREATE TABLE query with PARTITION on a timestamp column '**startTime**'.

```
CREATE TABLE project.table
PARTITION BY date(startTime) AS

SELECT 
    gameId, seasonID, date(startTime) as game_date, startTime, year
FROM `bigquery-public-data.baseball.games_wide`
WHERE YEAR = 2016
```

The table was created successfully and I can see the worker has the write phase, which is an indicator that something is writing to the table. However, when I go to 'Preview' the table, there is no data to display, and table size is 0 KB.

[image]

I tried remove the second line (i.e., PARTITION BY date(startTime)) when creating table, the data can be ingested and I am able to Preview it in console. It seems the PARTITION command is causing problem, but I can't tell where goes wrong. Any idea?

Comment: I ran your Query on my side and it was successful. I didn't modify your inquiry. I can also view the Preview the data on the table, Have you tried running a query on the created table?  Also I can suggest put a limit on your query since it will write thousands of data.( Since its at free tier it is possible has it limits)

Comment: Hi @KatherineChen, Are you still facing the issue?

Comment: @Nestor: Thank you for your comment & tips! so it seems to be my account issue.

Comment: @Prajna Rai T: yes, I just tried and the table is still showing 'There is no data to display'

Comment: @NestorCenizaJr: I ran the query on the table created and the result is empty. Basically the table is 0 KB

Comment: Did you try adding limt when querying the table? As mentioned in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/free-cloud-features#free-tier-usage-limits) 1 TB of querying per month is free and the Free Trial ends when you use all of your credit, or after 90 days, whichever happens first.

Comment: It is solved by creating a new dataset after the billing account is linked to the project. Thanks for your support. Very appreciated!

Comment: Hi @KatherineChen, I have posted the answer as Community wiki. So If my answer addressed your question, please consider upvoting and accepting it. If not, let me know so that the answer can be improved. Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 0):

As  you have mentioned in the comment this issue is resolved by creating a new dataset after the billing account is linked to the project.

You can follow this [tutorial](https://videolabs.jhanley.com/videolabs/Google-Cloud-Billing/#5) to create billing account and link it to project.